# How to make a UISearchBar Objective C request information to API and repopulate TableViewController.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently i show the first 100 users in a tableView Controller that leads to a User Profile if a person taps on it. But now i need to add a SearchBar so i can take the text they want and make a GET Request with the subjects and Rate of the user and get that response and repopulate the TableView.

Any Ideas how i can do that? I'm new on Objective-C and XCode making iOS apps. So please be patient. Thanks in Advance.

Note: I Don't need to search on the results i just need to repopulate them, because on internet i've found many tutorials based on searching existing table cell information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchBar has a textField inside , Which means it conforms to the UITextField delegates. 
One such delegate is , `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;` 
Set your searchBar delegate to self and implement this delegate.

When the user finishes typing this method will be called.You can extract the text from the textField parameter. Generate your URL setup an NSURL  asynchronous connection with the URL.
In the Completion handler of this NSURL connection update the datasource of your tableView and called  `[tableView reload]` on the main thread.

Comment: what is the delegate when the user presses the Search button on the keyboard? where can i get more information about this delegates on the SearchBar? Because on the official documentation i see SearchBar Controller doc but not for the Searchbar itself. thanks.

Comment: The search key is just a replacement for the return key on the key board. so this delegate will be called`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;` implement this method and return YES , you can generate your URL here.

Comment: i just copied the request and the dictionary loading onside the delegate and it made the call to the API and returned new data :) thanks for the tip.